# Can Prettier rules be applied using IntelliJ IDEA code style rules instead of the Prettier plugin?

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, code-formatting, prettier

I have a project that contains some TypeScript files which I would like to format using the [Prettier](https://prettier.io) format while editing in IntelliJ IDEA, so that my resulting code matches that of my colleagues.  Ideally, I only want to reformat the portions of the file I'm updating, so that my commits can be focused on my actual changes.

For other projects in IntelliJ IDEA I would typically use the built in code formatting and code style rules to format my code.  The built-in TypeScript rules do not match the Prettier rules, and it's unclear whether those rules are published anywhere in an IntelliJ format I could just import.

For this reason, I've investigated the [Prettier](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/prettier.html) IntelliJ IDEA plugin.  However, using this plugin requires some overhead; most notably, it requires a Node.js installation.

Is there an easy way to just use the Prettier rules using the standard IntelliJ reformatting functionality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IDEA can import some code style settings (indents and some others) when `.prettierrc` is present in the project even if the Prettier itself is not installed:

[image]

But unfortunately it's not possible for us to match Prettier behavior completely because it doesn't have a specification and introduces stylistic changes in patch releases.
So in general matching Prettier behavior with the built-in formatter is something that most likely will not happen.
It's expected that if someone is using Prettier, they will be either using the **Reformat with Prettier** action or set up Prettier to run on **Reformat Code** action (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/prettier.html#ws_prettier_default_formatter).

Comment: Why does your screenshot look like it was printed with a malfunctioning cartridge and has a coffee stain?

Comment: it's because of a [background image](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2022.1/setting-background-image.html) applied:)